# CSS Selecting children

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

How do I also give these changes below to the `div` tags, that is inside `.content-1`? Sorry if my question is vague, but I'm sure it's really simple.

I have this CSS:

```
.tabs input.tab-selector-1:checked ~ .content .content-1,
.tabs input.tab-selector-2:checked ~ .content .content-2,
.tabs input.tab-selector-3:checked ~ .content .content-3,
.tabs input.tab-selector-4:checked ~ .content .content-4 {
    z-index: 100;
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;

    -webkit-transition: opacity ease-out 0.2s 0.1s;
    -moz-transition: opacity ease-out 0.2s 0.1s;
    -o-transition: opacity ease-out 0.2s 0.1s;
    -ms-transition: opacity ease-out 0.2s 0.1s;
    transition: opacity ease-out 0.2s 0.1s;
}
```

Comment: Can you show your HTML? Also, I'm not sure what you want to select; the children of `.content-1`?

Comment: yes. The .content-1 is a div, but it has div's inside it. i want to target those divs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
.tabs input.tab-selector-1:checked ~ .content .content-1,
.tabs input.tab-selector-1:checked ~ .content .content-1 div {
    ...
}
```

Comment: sorry if i didnt state it clearly. I only want the .content-1 div's targeted when input.tab-selector-1 is checked :)

Comment: Updated - just add the div after the selection rule